# Aggregating and summing data in pandas dataframe. Is there a better way?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe of lacrosse statistics, with players, positions, goals scored etc. (stored in variable named da)

```
        Session Title   PLAYER STARTER  Number  G  A  SH  SOG  GB  DC  T/O  CT Pos
0          Opponent 1  Player1   False       1  0  0   0    0   0   0    0   0  M  
1          Opponent 2  Player1   False       1  0  0   0    0   1   0    0   0  M
2          Opponent 3  Player1   False       1  0  0   0    0   0   1    0   0  M
3          Opponent 4  Player1   False       1  0  0   0    0   0   0    0   0  M
4          Opponent 5  Player1   False       1  0  0   0    0   1   0    0   0  M
```

I wanted to see which positions score the most points, goals, and assists (points is just number of goals + number of assists)

I came up with the following:

```
poses = da.groupby(['Pos'])[['G','A']].sum()
poses = poses.drop(['GK'], axis = 0)
pose = poses.reset_index()
pose['Pts'] = pose['G']+pose['A']

opose = pd.melt(pose, id_vars='Pos', value_vars=['G', 'A'],
                var_name='G/A', value_name='Count')
#display(opose)

dims = (15, 11)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=dims)

plt.subplot(121)
sns.barplot(x=opose['Pos'], y=opose['Count'], hue=opose['G/A'])

plt.subplot(122)
sns.barplot(x=pose['Pos'], y=pose['Pts']);
```

So I grouped the original dataframe da by position and got the sums of goals and assists, then dropped goalkeepers and made a points column. After using melt I had two workable dataframes and plotted each using seaborn.

My main question is is there a better way to do this? I feel like it is a lot of work to simply find total goals etc. Must I use the groupby function? Can I obtain these visualizations more directly from the original dataframe? [image]

Comment: `da.groupby(['Pos'])[['G','A']].sum()` is a lot of work? it's pretty concise to me, especially when you consider how efficient it is when you have, say thousands of groups and hundreds of thousands of rows

Answer (score 0):

To keep things more concise you could use pandas own plotting functions. You don't have to melt the dataset then or reset the index. Here's an example of what you could do in just a few lines:

```
df_no_GK = df[df['Pos'] != 'GK']
group = df_no_GK.groupby(['Pos'])['G', 'A'].sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
group.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[0])
group.sum().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[1])
```